# Drawing Pie chart with ES6

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6, pie-chart, es6-class

I try to create my own chart library build upon D3.js and ES6 with animations and interactivity.

My problem is that drawing Pie chart requires some tween functions to animate pie chart nicely. I  try to write those tween functions with ES6.

My chart structure looks something like this:

```
class PieChart {
    constructor({w, h} = {}) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;

        ...

        this.onInit();
    }

    onInit() {
        this.radius = Math.min(this.w, this.h) / 2;

        this.arc = d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(this.radius - 20)
            .outerRadius(this.radius);

        this.pie = d3.pie();

        ...

        this.svg = d3.select("#id")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", this.w)
                .attr("height", this.h)

        this.drawChart();
    }

    drawChart() {
        this.arcs = this.svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${this.w / 2}, ${this.h / 2})`)
            .attr("class", "slices")
                .selectAll(".arc")
                .data(this.dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                    .attr("d", this.arc)
                    .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });

        ...

        const curryAttrTween = function() {
            let outerArc = this.arc;
            let radius = this.radius;

            return function(d) {                // <- PROBLEM: This inner function is never called
                this._current = this._current || d;
                let interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                this._current = interpolate(0);
                return function(t) {
                    let d2 = interpolate(t);
                    let pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                    return `translate(${pos})`;
                }
            }
        };

        let labels = this.svg.select(".label-name").selectAll("text")
            .data(this.pie(this.dataset), "key");

        labels
            .enter()
            .append("text")
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("class", "text")
                .text((d) => `${d.data.column}: ${d.data.data.count}`);

        labels
            .transition()
            .duration(666)
            .attrTween("d", curryAttrTween.bind(this)());

        labels
            .exit()
            .remove();    
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
drawChart() {
    ...

    const attrTween = function(d) {
        this._current = this._current || d;            // <- PROBLEM: Can't access scope 'this'
        let interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            let d2 = interpolate(t);
            let pos = this.arc.centroid(d2);
            pos[0] = this.radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
            return `translate(${pos})`;
        }
    }

    labels
        .transition()
        .duration(666)
        .attrTween("d", (d) => attrTween(d));

    ...
}
```

And my finally try:

```
drawChart() {
    ...

    labels
        .transition()
        .duration(666)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            let interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                let d2 = interpolate(t);
                let pos = this.arc.centroid(d2);                                // <- PROBLEM: Can't access this.arc
                pos[0] = this.radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);       // <- PROBLEM: Can't access this.radius
                return `translate(${pos})`;
            }
        });

    ...
}
```

All the above methods failed at some point. I pointed to the problems in my code, and I am not sure if and how this can be done in ES6.

Comment: To access scope in the first one, `const that = this;` and then use `that` in your `tween` function instead of `this`.

Comment: Thank you @RyanMorton, your solution works. I'll post answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't comment on the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49531667/3426353) ( not enough reputation :( ) I just want to point out that the newly created inner function (**interpolator**) won't have access to **interpolate** declared inside the **attrTween**:

```
drawChart() {
  //...

  // Use arrow function to lexically capture this scope.
  const interpolator = t => {
    let d2 = interpolate(t);                                     // <-- Reference Error
    let pos = this.arc.centroid(d2);
    pos[0] = this.radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return `translate(${pos})`;
  };

  labels
    .transition()
    .duration(666)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      let interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);       // <-- Declared here
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return interpolator;
    });

  //...
}
```

**ps.** I find the:

```
const self = this;
```

to be a good solution in this case, as its easier to read and reason about, even if its not exactly the best **ES6** way.

Answer (score 1):

Although your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49530141/4235784) works, it is an example of a *pre-ES6* solution, where you use a closure `const self = this;` to capture the outer `this` scope. This somehow feels like dodging your own question which asks for a ES6 solution.

The ES6 alternative to this approach would be to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead. One benefit of arrow functions is the fact, that they pick their `this` from the enclosing scope (lexical) they where defined in, whereas traditional functions have their own `this` preventing you from accessing the outer scope. This makes arrow functions especially useful as callbacks used in OOP, where you want to access the instance's properties from within the callback.

Your code can easily be rewritten to make use of this feature:

```
drawChart() {
  //...

  // Use arrow function to lexically capture this scope.
  const interpolator = t => {
    let d2 = interpolate(t);
    let pos = this.arc.centroid(d2);
    pos[0] = this.radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return `translate(${pos})`;
  };

  labels
    .transition()
    .duration(666)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      let interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return interpolator;
    });

  //...
}
```

Note, how this still uses a normal function as the *interpolator factory* callback provided to `.attrTween()` because this function relies on `this` to be bound to the current DOM element of the iteration instead of the outer scope.

---

Further reading: [*Chapter 13. Arrow Functions*](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html) from the excellent book [*Exploring ES6*](http://exploringjs.com/es6.html) by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer.

Comment: Awesome, I really like your solution. Thank you for sharing it. Also thanks for additional reading it really helps me understand problem better.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to post solution, that I found with help of @RyanMorton, for future self.

Solution is to define the variable `const self = this;`. This way we can access ES6's `this` inside anonymous function.

```
drawChart() {
    ...

    const self = this;
    labels
        .transition()
        .duration(666)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            let interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                let d2 = interpolate(t);
                let pos = self.arc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = self.radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return `translate(${pos})`;
            }
        });

    ...
}
```